# Split by | and table the frequencies

Tags: r

I have a data.frame composed by one column that looks like this:

> ```
>        E1| 
>        E3|SAMD11 
>        E3|SAMD11 
>        E2|SAMD11 
>        E10|SAMD11 
>        E10|SAMD11 
>        E10|SAMD11 
>        E10|SAMD11 
>        E10|SAMD11 
>        E1|
>        E2|
>        E3| 
>        E3|PERM1
>        E9|AL645608.7;HES4;ISG15
>        E3|EGFR;HES4;PIK3CA
> ```

E* are from 1 to 10
I would like lo count how many E* I have for each gene removing or ignoring cases where E| is followed by empty.
The desired output would be:

> ```
> SAMD11: E3: 2
> SAMD11: E2: 1
> SAMD11: E10: 5
> PERM1:  E3: 1 
> HES4:   E9: 1
> HES4:   E3: 1
> AL645608.7 E9:1
> ISG15:  E9: 1
> EGFR:   E3: 1
> PIK3CA E3: 1
> ```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#split on | then separate on ; 
df %>% extract(id, into=c('id','gene'), regex="(.*)\\|(.*)?") %>% 
       separate_rows(gene, sep='\\;') %>% 
       filter(gene!="") %>% 
       count(gene, id)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
   gene       id        n
   <chr>      <chr> <int>
 1 AL645608.7 E9        1
 2 EGFR       E3        1
 3 HES4       E3        1
 4 HES4       E9        1
 5 ISG15      E9        1
 6 PERM1      E3        1
 7 PIK3CA     E3        1
 8 SAMD11     E10       5
 9 SAMD11     E2        1
10 SAMD11     E3        2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_data) # convert to data.table

# add two columns, key and val, from the input column col
my_data[ , c('key', 'val') := tstrsplit(col, '|', fixed = TRUE)]

# drop rows with nothing on the RHS of |
my_data = my_data[!is.na(val)]

# unnest the ;-separated values
my_data = my_data[ , {
  l = strsplit(val, ';', fixed = TRUE)
  .(E = rep(E, each = lengths(l)), val = unlist(val))
}]

# count
my_data[ , .N, keyby = .(E, val)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`,  read the column with `read.table` into a two column `data.frame`, then split the second column with `strsplit`, convert it to a two column data.frame, get the frequency with `table` and convert it to `data.frame`

```
d1 <- read.table(text = df1$id, header = FALSE, sep="|", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
out <- subset(as.data.frame(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(d1$V2, ";"), 
            d1$V1))[2:1])), Freq > 0)
names(out) <- c("id", "gene", "n")
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#    id       gene n
#1   E9 AL645608.7 1
#2   E3       EGFR 1
#3   E3       HES4 1
#4   E9       HES4 1
#5   E9      ISG15 1
#6   E3      PERM1 1
#7   E3     PIK3CA 1
#8   E3     SAMD11 2
#9   E2     SAMD11 1
#10 E10     SAMD11 5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("E1|", "E3|SAMD11", "E3|SAMD11", "E2|SAMD11", 
"E10|SAMD11", "E10|SAMD11", "E10|SAMD11", "E10|SAMD11", "E10|SAMD11", 
"E1|", "E2|", "E3|", "E3|PERM1", "E9|AL645608.7;HES4;ISG15", 
"E3|EGFR;HES4;PIK3CA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```